# Create a poetry pypi project & install it with pipx

Tags: python, python-poetry, pipx

I have a [python project](https://github.com/Cyfrin/dup-hawk) that I have uploaded to pypi, and now I am attempting to install it with pipx:

```
pipx install dup-hawk
```

however, I'm getting:

```
No apps associated with package dup-hawk. Try again with '--include-deps' to include apps of dependent packages, which are listed above. If you are
attempting to install a library, pipx should not be used. Consider using pip or a similar tool instead.
```

I think this is due to me not having an entry script for my project defined in poetry. How do I define an entry point in a poetry project so it can be installed with pipx?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `tool.poetry.scripts` in your `pyproject.toml` line to use pipx with a cli:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
dup-hawk = 'dup_hawk.dup_hawk:dup_hawk_click'
```